# How to make query-replace automatically fill what I want to replace with marked text?

Tags: region, query-replace

I want to select some text somewhere in a buffer, call `query-replace` and then type (or paste from `kill-ring`) only the second argument, `TO-STRING`, (and make the selected text count as `FROM-STRING`).

I want a replacement to be performed within the entire buffer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use library [Replace+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplacePlus) ([`replace+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/replace%2b.el)) then you can just customize option `search/replace-region-as-default-flag` to non-`nil`.  That gives you the region text as `FROM` text default, so you can just hit `RET` to accept that.

> **`search/replace-region-as-default-flag`** is a variable defined in `replace+.el`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means use the active region text as default for search/replace.
>
> That is, if the region is currently active then use its text as the
> default input.  All text properties are removed from the text.
>
> Note that in this case the active region is not used to limit the
> search/replacement scope.  But in that case you can of course just
> narrow the buffer temporarily to restrict the operation scope.
>
> A non-`nil` value of this option takes precedence over the use of option
> `search/replace-2nd-sel-as-default-flag`.  To give that option
> precedence over using the active region, you can set this option to
> nil and use `region-or-non-nil-symbol-name-nearest-point` as the value
> of option `search/replace-default-fn`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

You can also use command `toggle-search/replace-region-as-default` anytime to toggle the option value.

---

But if you really want not to even have to hit `RET` to accept the region text then you'll need to write a command that uses that as the `FROM` arg to `query-replace` and then interactively reads the other args.

This should do that:

```lisp
(defun my-q-r (from-string to-string
               &optional delimited start end backward region-noncontiguous-p)
  "Query-replace text of active region with text you're prompted for."
  (interactive
   (progn
     (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
     (let* ((from (if (use-region-p)
              (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))
            (query-replace-read-from "Query replace" nil)))
        (to (if (consp from) (prog1 (cdr from) (setq from (car from)))
          (query-replace-read-to from "Query replace" nil))))
       (list from to
         (or (and current-prefix-arg (not (eq current-prefix-arg '-)))
         (and (plist-member (text-properties-at 0 from) 'isearch-regexp-function)
                      (get-text-property 0 'isearch-regexp-function from)))
         (and current-prefix-arg (eq current-prefix-arg '-))))))
  (deactivate-mark)
  (query-replace from-string to-string delimited start end backward region-noncontiguous-p))
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It'll replace only the following occurrences but I presume I just need to add the "jump to file start" somewhere.

Comment: Yes. That's the case for query-replace commands. If you want, you can put this at the beginning of the code that defines the command: `(goto-char (point-min))`, after the `interactive` spec.

Answer (score 1):

```
M-w M-< M-% C-y RET <replacement> RET !
```

does the trick.

Comment: I want to be able to pass the `<replacement>` from my kill ring as well.

Comment: You can have multiple kills in the kill-ring. C-y to yank the last killed and M-y to yank the previous ones. (info "(emacs) Yanking Early Kills"). You can also use registers (info "(emacs)registers").

Comment: Yes, indeed, but this feature doesn't work with `query-replace` function (I'm using `counsel-yank-pop` for `M-y` binding).

Comment: I confirm, even the default `M-y` keybinding which is `yank-pop` doesn't work that way, because it attempts to interactively ask the text to yank, which ofc doesn't work if you are already in the minibuffer. Judging by docs it seems like passing an ARG should override such behavior, but either I'm misreading it or the docs are wrong/the function is buggy, passing an ARG does not change that behavior.

Comment: gigiair, @achempion so, good news is I found a solution to the `M-y` problem! It is easy to define your own function that pastes the previous kill-ring content as `(defun yank-prev-killring () (interactive) (insert (nth 1 kill-ring)))` and then bind it with `(global-set-key (kbd "M-y") #'yank-prev-killring)`. Feel free to add that to the answer! ^_^